# Attempt to read key via int 16h ends in VM reboot

Tags: assembly, x86, rust, keyboard, bios

I was trying to add keyboard interaction to code from [this example](https://os.phil-opp.com/minimal-rust-kernel/). Consider the following files:

> Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "kernelhello"
version = "0.0.1"

[dependencies]
bootloader = "0.3.12"

[package.metadata.bootimage]
default-target = "build.json"
```

> build.json

```
{
  "llvm-target": "x86_64-unknown-none",
  "data-layout": "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128",
  "arch": "x86_64",
  "target-endian": "little",
  "target-pointer-width": "64",
  "target-c-int-width": "32",
  "os": "none",
  "executables": true,
  "linker-flavor": "ld.lld",
  "linker": "rust-lld",
  "panic-strategy": "abort",
  "disable-redzone": true,
  "features": "-mmx,-sse,+soft-float"
}
```

> src/main.rs

```
// src/main.rs
#![feature(asm)]

#![no_std] // don't link the Rust standard library
#![no_main] // disable all Rust-level entry points

use core::panic::PanicInfo;

/// This function is called on panic.
#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
    loop {}
}


#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn _start() -> ! {
    let mut HELLO: &mut [u8] = &mut b"Hello World!".clone();
    let vga_buffer = 0xb8000 as *mut u8;

    let mut z = 0;
    loop {
        for (i, byte) in HELLO.iter_mut().enumerate() {
            unsafe {
                z += 14;
                z %= 4000;
                *vga_buffer.offset(z + i as isize * 2) = *byte;
                *vga_buffer.offset(z + i as isize * 2 + 1) = 0xa;
                asm!("mov $$0, %ah\nint $$0x16");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately,  an attempt to do `bootimage run` ends with an image that is stuck in a reboot loop - which doesn't happen if I comment out the `asm!` call. Here's a disassembly:

```
➜  rust-kernel-hello objdump -D -b binary -Mintel,x86-64  -m i386 target/build/debug/bootimage-kernelhello.bin | grep -C5 'ef01'
    eef0:       00 
    eef1:       48 8b 84 24 d0 00 00    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp+0xd0]
    eef8:       00 
    eef9:       48 89 84 24 00 01 00    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x100],rax
    ef00:       00 
    ef01:       48 8d bc 24 f0 00 00    lea    rdi,[rsp+0xf0]
    ef08:       00 
    ef09:       e8 72 fe ff ff          call   0xed80
    ef0e:       48 89 94 24 20 01 00    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x120],rdx
    ef15:       00 
    ef16:       48 89 84 24 18 01 00    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x118],rax
--
    f119:       48 89 04 24             mov    QWORD PTR [rsp],rax
    f11d:       48 8b 04 24             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp]
    f121:       c6 00 0a                mov    BYTE PTR [rax],0xa
    f124:       b4 00                   mov    ah,0x0
    f126:       cd 16                   int    0x16
    f128:       e9 d4 fd ff ff          jmp    0xef01
    f12d:       48 8d 3d cc 0a 00 00    lea    rdi,[rip+0xacc]        # 0xfc00
    f134:       e8 07 04 00 00          call   0xf540
    f139:       0f 0b                   ud2    
    f13b:       48 8d 3d e6 0a 00 00    lea    rdi,[rip+0xae6]        # 0xfc28
    f142:       e8 f9 03 00 00          call   0xf540
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are creating an x86_64 file, but try to debug it as i386.

Comment: @zx485 is it cause of the problem or does it just mean that my debugging efforts are wrong?

Comment: It just affects your debugging code display. But this way it's impossible to spot the bug (in the assembly)

Comment: @zx485 is it better now?

Comment: If the bootloader puts your processor in _long mode_, you cannot BIOS interrupts like `int 16h`. They only work in _real mode_.

Comment: If you want to add keyboard support to your kernel you'll need to access the hardware directly. For a PS/2 keyboard that's relatively easily, for a USB keyboard you'll either have to depend on the motherboard emulating a PS/2 keyboard or write your own USB stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to explain *zx485*'s comment in more detail:

I've often seen that assembly language beginners are confused about what instructions like `int` (x86), `syscall` (MIPS) or `SWI` (ARM) actually do.

Actually, these instructions are a special form of `call` instruction: They call some sub-routine which is typically located in the operating system.

64-bit x86 CPUs have different operating modes. One of them is named "real mode". In this mode the CPU can only execute 16-bit code.

The BIOS sub-routine that can be called using `int 0x16` only works when the PC is operating in "real mode".

The fact that your program is a 64-bit program (registers like `rax` are used) tells us that your CPU is not running in real mode.

If you are writing your own operating system, you can define own sub-routines that are called by certain `int` instructions:

You can define a sub-routine that is called by `int 0x16` which reads the keyboard and another one called by `int 0x10` writing to the screen.

However, you are also free to define that `int 0x16` is used for writing to the screen and `int 0x10` is used for hard disk access in your operating system.

And in every case you'll have to write the sub-routines yourself because the existing sub-routines in the BIOS cannot be used in any other operating mode than "real mode". (This is what *Ross Ridge* is indicating in his comment.)